# Alternative to RF in regression

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, random-forest, prediction

I am trying to use RF in sklearn to predict our book sales. Our data is a set of dates, unit sales, and relevant discounts. Generally speaking, we sell a lot of books around their release date and then it quickly tapers off with clear peaks around discounts. I’ve been using random forest to predict the next day change, since trying to predict the raw sales wouldn’t generalize. Does anyone have any suggestions for different methodologies?

Comment: multivariate linear regression (lm, glm).

Comment: @AlexeyBurnakov _Multivariate_ or _multiple_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised you began with random forests.  In my understanding RF is best suited to situations in which you have a great many candidates for predictor variables, and little theory to guide your choice of predictors.  Here you have few predictors and good reason to believe that sales will follow soon after discounts are made available.

As @Alexey Burnakov mentioned, linear modeling may help; the biggest issues will probably be 1) what lags to test between discounting and sales, 2) how many of them to try at once, and 3) how to respond to the serial correlation and/or correlated residuals you obtain.  Time series modeling may serve you better.  It seems a lot of people have praised Rob J. Hyndman's writings in this area.  I also found Mark Pickup's introduction (Sage, about $18) to be detailed and helpful.